# Intel® oneAPI for Mac OS in 2024

Tags: macos, intel-mkl, intel-oneapi

I was trying to install Intel® oneAPI on my Mac but it seams that Intel has discontinued the support for Mac. [intel.com](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/oneapi/installation-guide-macos/2024-0/overview.html)

Can I somehow work around it? Or download an old Version of oneAPI?

I was trying to install PyMesh and I encountering issues related to the absence of the Intel Math Kernel Library (MKL) on my Mac. PyMesh relies on MKL for certain mathematical computations. Since MKL seams not to be provided as a standalone installer for macOS, I wonted to install the Intel oneAPI toolkit, which includes MKL.

Answer (score 1):

You can install an older version from the available disk images, for example for version 2023.2.0:

```
MACOS_BASEKIT_URL=https://registrationcenter-download.intel.com/akdlm/IRC_NAS/cd013e6c-49c4-488b-8b86-25df6693a9b7/m_BaseKit_p_2023.2.0.49398.dmg
MACOS_HPCKIT_URL=https://registrationcenter-download.intel.com/akdlm/IRC_NAS/edb4dc2f-266f-47f2-8d56-21bc7764e119/m_HPCKit_p_2023.2.0.49443.dmg
```

You need to download it using curl or the like and then attach the image using `hdiutil`:

```
  curl -L $MACOS_BASEKIT_URL > m_BASEKit.dmg
  hdiutil attach m_BASEKit.dmg
  sudo /Volumes/"$(basename "$MACOS_BASEKIT_URL" .dmg)"/bootstrapper.app/Contents/MacOS/bootstrapper -s \
    --action install \
    --eula=accept \
    --continue-with-optional-error=yes \
    --log-dir=.
  hdiutil detach /Volumes/"$(basename "$MACOS_BASEKIT_URL" .dmg)" -quiet
  rm m_BASEKit.dmg

  curl -L $MACOS_HPCKIT_URL > m_HPCKit.dmg
  hdiutil attach m_HPCKit.dmg
  sudo /Volumes/"$(basename "$MACOS_HPCKIT_URL" .dmg)"/bootstrapper.app/Contents/MacOS/bootstrapper -s \
    --action install \
    --eula=accept \
    --continue-with-optional-error=yes \
    --log-dir=.
  hdiutil detach /Volumes/"$(basename "$MACOS_HPCKIT_URL" .dmg)" -quiet
  rm m_HPCKit.dmg
```

Then activate the environment variables using

```
  source /opt/intel/oneapi/setvars.sh
```